# ExchangeService.FindItems()

Tags: c#, .net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I've been requested to create an application that should create a common base from 3 different email addresses sources and update each base taking the most common updated dataset. 
Among the three sources I have an Exchange server Contacts addressbook. I know that I can access such data trough EWS and in specific I should probably use the ExchangeService.FindPeople() method or maybe FindPersona().
This should work but, since I'm looking only for new/updated contacts, it will load significantly the server (maybe not for new records but I cannot understand how to retrieve update records) and this it's not a good practice.
I've found in MSDN docs a way to be notified on updates on message base but there's nothin related on updates on contacts:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn458791(v=exchg.150).aspx

Is there something to be notified on updates on contacts (even trough third party products/APIs).

P.S. I would like to code in C# (or other .NET languages) but I'm open to anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to check for newly created contacts by iterating through the contacts and accessing the `DateTimeCreated` property on each.

To check for updated contacts, you could use the `LastModifiedTime` property.

```
// Get the number of items in the Contacts folder.
ContactsFolder contactsfolder = ContactsFolder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Contacts);

// Set the number of items to the number of items in the Contacts folder or 50, whichever is smaller.
int numItems = contactsfolder.TotalCount < 50 ? contactsfolder.TotalCount : 50;

// Instantiate the item view with the number of items to retrieve from the Contacts folder.
ItemView view = new ItemView(numItems);

// To keep the request smaller, request only the DateTimeCreated and LastModifiedTime properties.
view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ContactSchema.DateTimeCreated, ContactSchema.LastModifiedTime);

// Retrieve the items in the Contacts folder that have the properties that you selected.
FindItemsResults<Item> contactItems = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts, view);

// Display the list of contacts. 
foreach (Item item in contactItems)
{
    if (item is Contact)
    {
        Contact contact = item as Contact;
        if (contact.DateTimeCreated.Date == DateTime.Today.Date)
        {
           //Notify - Newly created contact
        }

        if (contact.LastModifiedTime.Date == DateTime.Today.Date)
        {
           //Notify - Newly modified contact
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh yes ! Thank you... I see *FindItem()* can also use a query to select among items... maybe the same iteraction can be solved to a properly formed query.

Comment: You can find the example here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/dd633693(v=exchg.80)

Answer (score 0):

This is simple example to find contact by nikname. You can find a more advaced search [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/dd633693(v=exchg.80)).

```
// Create a view with a page size of 1.
ItemView view = new ItemView(1);

// Create the search filter.
SearchFilter searchFilter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(ContactSchema.NickName, "806555335");

FindItemsResults<Item> contactItems = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts, searchFilter, view);

if(contactItems != null && contactItems.Count()>0){
    //contact found!
    Contact contact = contactItems.First() as Contact;
}
```